# How to consume web service rest with java?

Tags: java, json, http

I have this error:

```
"Conectando: http://graph.facebook.com/pivotalsoftware
Consulta: {"PARAM1": "pivotalsoftware"}
Error ocurrido
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://graph.facebook.com/pivotalsoftware "
```

and i can't understand it so help me please!

```
public class Essai {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    URL url = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/pivotalsoftware");
    //Insert your JSON query request
    String query = "{'PARAM1': 'pivotalsoftware'}";
    //It change the apostrophe char to double colon char, to form a correct JSON string
    query=query.replace("'", "\"");

    try{
        //make connection
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
        //It Content Type is so importan to support JSON call
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        Msj("Conectando: " + url.toString());
        //use post mode
        urlc.setDoOutput(true);
        urlc.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

        //send query
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(urlc.getOutputStream());
        ps.print(query);
        Msj("Consulta: " + query);
        ps.close();

        //get result
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));
        String l = null;
        while ((l=br.readLine())!=null) {
            Msj(l);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Msj("Error ocurrido");
        Msj(e.toString());
    }
}

private static void Msj(String texto){
    System.out.println(texto);

    // TODO code application logic here
}
```

Comment: `curl -v -X HEAD http://graph.facebook.com/pivotalsoftware` has a `200 OK`. The same for any browser.

Comment: .... "Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL" do a research.

Comment: Just curious: would it change anything if you used application/json instead of application/xml for the Content-Type?

Answer (score 0):

Class below should help you

```java
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintStream;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;
    
    public class userAuthetication {
        //5213
        
        
        
        public static void userlogin(String usrname,  String pwd) throws IOException{
            
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://140.104.135.204:50/Directory-Rest.aspx?Function=Authenticate");
                //Insert your JSON query request
                
                String query = "{'Username':'"+ usrname + "',"+ "'Password':'" + pwd + "'}";
                //It change the apostrophe char to double colon char, to form a correct JSON string
                query=query.replace("'", "\"");
                
                //make connection
                URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
                //It Content Type is so importan to support JSON call
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
                Msj("Conectando: " + url.toString());
                //use post mode
                urlc.setDoOutput(true);
                urlc.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    
                //send query
                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(urlc.getOutputStream());
                ps.print(query);
                Msj("Consulta: " + query);
                ps.close();
    
                //get result
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));
                String l = null;
                while ((l=br.readLine())!=null) {
                    Msj(l);
                }
                
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Msj("Error ocurrido");
                Msj(e.toString());
            }
        }
         private static void Msj(String texto){
           System.out.println(texto);
       }
        
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible, I'd not recommend to build your own REST Client (incorporating `URLConnection` or etc. low-level APIs) unless it's really necessary.

There are several ways to do this. I'll draw your attention on some most popular ones:

- **Spring's [`RestTemplate`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/)**, which uses the Jackson JSON processing library to process the incoming data. (updates with Spring [`WebClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html));
- **JAX-RS** ([Jersey](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/) implementation), which has several ways to consume different Media Types.

These are the easiest and most popular, performing facilities to create REST Client, hence consume REST Resource.

This is all it takes for `RestTemplate` to consume REST resource:

```
 public static void getRESTResource() {
    final String uri = "your host here;
 
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class); //note, that there are many overloaded methods for different variations of parameters;
    CustomType result = restTemplate.getForObject(REST_URI, CustomType.class, params); //to bind incoming data to your CustomType
 }
```

Example of JAX-RS Client can be found [here](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jaxrs-client002.html).